# Is it possible to change URL when returning ModelAndView from WEB-INF?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, modelandview

I'm using Spring MVC and I'm wondering is it possible to change URL when I return ModelAndView (the view is situated at the WEB-INF folder, so redirecting to it is not working) from the controller? I mean when I return it the URL is the previous one, and its obvious because dispatcher is working, not the redirecting.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView authenticate(@RequestParam("login") String login, @RequestParam("password") String password) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        User user = userDao.getUserByLogin(login);
        if (user != null && user.getPassword().equals(password)) {
            modelAndView.addObject("user", user);
            modelAndView.setViewName("home");
        }
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

So my `home` model is in WEB-INF folder, so `return redirect:/home` will not work for it. Yes, I can redirect it with `return home`, but in that case the URL will not change.

Answer (score 2):

Use `redirect:/url` to some other method and return the view.

When redirecting the model attributes won't available in new method so to get that in redirected method set it in `RedirectFlashAttributes`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: As I said my view is in WEB-INF folder so 'redirect:/url' will not work for it as it's cant be reached with GET request.

Comment: When ever its your view it can be reachable. If you can post your code .

Comment: It's reachable by just returning the view, not redirecting. BUT! If I return the view-name, it redirects it with NO URL changes.